# How to setup ResponseType (Net Core 6) based on JSON Schema

Tags: json, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, response, jsonschema

I have a large number of APIs, each without a strong class definition for output, like this

```vb
Return Ok(New With {
    .ServerDecryptPass = ServerDecryptPass,
    .VmConnectionAdminDecryptPass = VmConnectionAdminDecryptPass,
    .DockerHubDecryptPass = DockerHubDecryptPass,
    .DockerRegistryDecryptPass = DockerRegistryDecryptPass,
    .VmConnectionUserDecryptPass = VmConnectionUserDecryptPass
})
```

Swagger, of course, doesn't see anything for response type in this case

[image: JSON result]

The simplest way to formalize this JSON result is creating a JSON schema, for example in this case it looks like

```json
    {                                                      
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "serverDecryptPass": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "item1": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "number"
              }
            },
            "item2": {
              "type": "null"
            }
          }
        },
        "vmConnectionAdminDecryptPass": {
    ...
    }
```

I have a hundreds of APIs and I am searching for a simple way to formalize the output of the APIs in order to generate a frontend automatically from this backend API. I searched for a simple way to setup the attribute, **ProducesResponseType**, based on XML schema or maybe even an example of an API result.

What is a possible solution?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [OpenAPI.Net](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET).  It can handle a lot of the swagger stuff for you, including generating schemas for your types.

Comment: @gregsdennis, I have workable OpenApi in my project, I show result of OpenApi in my screen above, my question how to setup ResponseType (how to setup input data for OpenApi)  quickly (I prefer based on JSON schema).